# How do I acquire Focused, Berserk and Enraged state in Warhammer 40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr

There are many unexplained *states* in this game, I found what they actually do, but I wasn't able to figure out how to activate them.

- **Focused** state

> Various conditions can cause a Focused state. While Focused, the player gains a 50% bonus for HP and Suppression regeneration.

- **Berserk** state

> If a Player has a Berserk token active, they are considered to be in a Berserk state. This means gaining a 10% movement speed bonus regardless of the number of active tokens, and gaining a 1% damage and damage reduce bonus per active token. The active Berserk token number is decreased by 1 per second.

- **Enraged** state

> If a Player has an Enraged token active, they are considered to be in an Enraged state. This means gaining a 3% damage bonus for every Enraged token. The maximum cap for Enraged tokens is 10 and each attack consumes a token.

(There's even a pretty cool [official compendium](https://neocoregames.com/en/community/warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr-compendium), but it's missing this part.)

Several equipments/relics have attributes related to these states, for what I understood the game gives you tokens and then the state is triggered. Tokens activation could be related to rare relics attributes, but I haven't found none yet.
And no idea about those "various conditions" that can cause a Focused state.

So, how do I receive a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there are rare gears (from Relic quality and above) that may have a unique skill which activates those particular tokens. Those tokens are earned when doing specific actions like killing an enemy (for berserk), or don't move (for focused).